# Strange shadow being cast/ lights not diffusing correctly

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting, geometry

I'm having an issue in one of my scenes where a half of the wall is darker than the other and the lights aren't illuminating it. There are no objects in the scene that could be making this darkening effect, and when I replace the wall with an empty plane the shadow goes away. I'm assuming it may be a texture issue causing this I just don't know how to fix it. Also, all faces are pointing the correct way and the wall is only one face anyway. If anyone has a solution to this help would be greatly appreciated. (also this effect happens a little on another face with the same texture, but not on a mirrored face with the same texture, so weird and annoying) [image: Lighting Issue]

Comment: hello, could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I'm new to blender stack exchange, how do I share my .blend file? Also I've found that the Normal map image is what seems to be causing this issue, I need to figure out how to get it to not do that now.

Comment: you can pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), and share the file with workupload.com

Comment: Alright, The scene is using all 4k textures so the file is very large

Comment: I've figured out the issue. The Normal map of the texture was using sRGB color space for whatever reason, changing it to filmic log or non-color worked for me. It probably worked on filmic log because I am using Filmic log for my color management in  renders.

Comment: oh ok, great then  ;)  ....